# How to bulk update using Mongo JS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert a new field based on another field in all the documents. Currently, I have close to 330millions documents. Updating one by one is taking a lot of time. Below is my sample code,

```
var db = connect('127.0.0.1:27017/sampleDatabase');
print('Database connect');
 
collectionsList = [1 .... 100];
 
collectionsList.forEach(addNewTimeField);
 
function addNewTimeField(value, index, array){ 
    let collectionName = 'name_' + value;
    db[collectionName].find().forEach(function(doc) {
        db[collectionName].update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{"ts": new Date(doc.timeStamp)}});   
    });
    db[collectionName].createIndex({ "ts" : 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 31622400 }, { "background": true} );
}
```

Is there an way I can use bulk update to updates multiple records simultaneously? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using this [mongo-js](https://github.com/mongo-js/mongojs)? if yes then please provide installed version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) from MongoDB v4.2,

- use [updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html)
- [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) convert timestamp to date, from MongoDB v4.0

```
db[collectionName].updateMany(
  {}, 
  [{ 
    $set: { ts: { $toDate: "$timeStamp" } }
  }]
);
```

---

Second option is [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html), this will update all records in single transaction,

```
async function addNewTimeField(value, index, array){ 
  let collectionName = 'name_' + value;
  let allDocs = await db[collectionName].find({}, { timeStamp: 1 });
  let updateAllDocs = allDocs.map(({ _id, timeStamp }) => ({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { _id: ObjectId(_id) },
      update: { ts: new Date(timeStamp) }
    }
  }));
  db[collectionName].bulkWrite(updateAllDocs);
  db[collectionName].createIndex({ "ts" : 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 31622400 }, { "background": true} );
}
```

> bulkWrite query prepared without testing, let me know if you getting any problem.

Comment: [MongoJS API](https://github.com/mongo-js/mongojs) may not have the `updateMany` nor the `bulkWrite` methods on the collection object, just check with the OP if the version they are using supports the above APIs

Comment: you are right, i just check in [collection library](https://github.com/mongo-js/mongojs/blob/master/lib/collection.js) file, they have support of updateMany() method but they have not updated documentation, and bulkWrite is not supporting. let me confirm first.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the solution without the find part and with `multi` set to true, which is going to execute the update for every document on the collection

```js
var db = connect('127.0.0.1:27017/sampleDatabase');
print('Database connect');
 
collectionsList = [1 .... 100];
 
collectionsList.forEach(addNewTimeField);
 
function addNewTimeField(value, index, array){ 
    let collectionName = 'name_' + value;
    db[collectionName].update({}, {$set:{"ts":  { "$toDate": "$timeStamp" }, {multi: true});   
    db[collectionName].createIndex({ "ts" : 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 31622400 }, { "background": true} );
}
```

Comment: In this case `doc` will be undefined and throws an error on `new Date(doc.timeStamp)`

Comment: You are right, do you think that using the dollar sign operator in order to reference the timeStamp of every document will help?

Comment: That depends on whether the MongoJS version the OP is using supports the `update()` or `updateMany()` methods which [update documents with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)